# Why collection types check happen only at compile, and Array types are checked at compile time and Runtime

Tags: java, generics, collections

Why collection types check happen only at compile time, 
and Array types are checked at compile time and Runtime.

Comment: because of the dimension and memory allocation.

Comment: Possibly because generics were hacked into the language in Java 5 in such a way as not to break back-compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

Java uses type-erasure because as pointed out in comment by @khelwood generics were an after thought and brought into the language in 1.5.

Also, runtime type checking is computationally expensive, so the checking is handled at compile time to alleviate the need for checking during runtime.

Also, as pointed out by InjuredThePatient in the comments, what you are seeing as "runtime type checking" with `ArrayList`s is actually memory allocation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Reference arrays have to runtime checking as their weird behaviour allows statically unsafe implicit conversions. You can assign a `String[]` to an `Object[]` and store a `Thread` into it. If that were unchecked at runtime (it throws an `ArrayStoreException`) then type-safety would be broken and hence mobile-code security.

The complexity of generics has resulted in various obscure compiler bugs. Those are relatively benign, but if generics was left to the JVM to enforce they would have been vulnerabilities. It turns out that the specification itself is unsound.

Java would have been a better language if `Object[]` was the only type of reference array. Would have also forced `main` to be something more sensible.